# Test Coverage for Future method salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex-code

Hi i trying to get coverage for a class that has few future method (for web service call) and few concrete static methods. but after calling future method, i am unable to call other methods... Can you please tell me how to take coverage for future method and web service calls.

my class structure :

```
public with sharing class AccountSynchController { 
 @future (callout=true)
    public static void importAccount(Set<Id> ids) {

    }
 @future (callout=true)
    public static void importContact(Set<Id> ids) {

    }
}

[future methods are called from trigger]

Test Class Code : 


        VAT__c testVat = new VAT__c();
    testVat.Code__c = '3';
    insert testVat;        

        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';
        testAccount.VATSales__c = testVat.Id;
        testAccount.VATPurchase__c = testVat.Id;
        testAccount.KvK_Nummer__c = '12312312';
        testAccount.PhoneExt__c = '12312312';
        testAccount.Website = '12312312';
        testAccount.BillingPostalCode = '12312312';
        testAccount.BillingCity = '12312312';
        testAccount.Fax = '12312312';
        testAccount.Phone = '12312312';
        testAccount.BillingStreet = '12312312';
        testAccount.BTW_Nummer__c = '12312312';
        testAccount.BillingCountry = '12312312';
        testAccount.BillingState = '12312312';
        testAccount.BTW_Nummer__c = '12312312'; 
        testAccount.E_mail__c = 'test@gmail.com';
        testAccount.Taal__c = 'NL';
        testAccount.SalesPaymentConditionCode__c = '15';
        testAccount.Code__c = '102';
        testAccount.fromExact__c = false;
        testAccount.Exact_Id__c = '123123';
        insert testAccount;

        Contact testContact = new Contact();
        testContact.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
        testContact.Birthdate = system.today();
        testContact.Conact_Exact_Number__c = '12312312312';
        testContact.Email = 'test@gmail.com';
        testContact.FirstName = 'first';
        testContact.Title_Code__c = 'Mr.';
        testContact.Geslacht__c = 'M';
        testContact.Initials__c = 'I';
        testContact.Language_Code__c = 'NL';
        testContact.LastName = 'last';
        testContact.MiddleName__c = 'middle';
        testContact.Phone = '12321312312';
        testContact.fromExact__c = false;
        insert testContact;
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Begin your unit test by calling [Test.startTest()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm), then run your test inserts.  Finish by calling [Test.stopTest()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm).  Calling that last method ensures that your @future method will have fired.  After that you can do your assertions to validate the trigger's actions.

Comment: Beautiful, my friend, thanks.  This post was a ray of sunshine on an otherwise cloudy, Apex-filled day.

Comment: I think instead of Test.endTest(), it should be Test.stopTest(). I don't see an endTest() method. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm

Answer (score 2):

Extending on Adam's answer to test the callouts you will need to either make use of the `Test.isRunningTest()` method to give you a chance to emulate returning the data from your web service - it's not the best but it's the commonly accepted way.

The other option is to use some mocking and injection but this isn't as straight forward as it should be so most people go for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Since is impossible to make a webservice call-out directly from your testing class, you have to write an addiction mock class. Purpose of that is to generate a fake response.

```
// This causes a fake response to be generated
    Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());
```

where WebServiceMock.class is the class above-mentioned.
After that you are able to invoke the true webservice call-out method in your test class.

Check the following link for further information.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm